# Wordpress user role, that can only edit users with another user role?

Tags: wordpress

I created a new user role, but I need this user role to only be able to edit users with another user role, I do not want this new user role to be able to edit users like, editors, author, etc...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can add roles so:

```
   $result = add_role(
        'editor_of_users',
        __( 'Editor of Users' ),
        array(
           'edit_users' => true,
           // Add more capabilities...
        )
    );
    if ( null !== $result ) {
        echo 'Yay! New role created!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Oh... the editor_of_users role already exists.';
    }
```

For more information you can read the documentation about: [add_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

And the all users capabilities here: [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

EDIT:

Read this post: to know how add to users the capabilities to edit specific roles... 
[How to allow an user role to create a new user under a role which lower than his level only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188863/how-to-allow-an-user-role-to-create-a-new-user-under-a-role-which-lower-than-his)

I hope you resolve it... Good Look! ;)

Comment: I have already created the role, I need to limit the role to be able to edit ONLY users with the "Subscriber" role

Comment: @Brooke I' ve edited my answer, I've added a link that you can guide you to resolve your problem... Good Look! ;) I hope I have been helpful...